# Is there a way to edit the uploaded assets in GEE in GEE itself?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking for a way to edit the shape filed uploaded as assets in GEE. I uploaded the training set for the classification in GEE and now want to remove a few of the points from that assets. As those points are not right. Is there a way that I can edit that asset in GEE itself or can move that asset to geometry and then edit